# Proxy Re-Encryption with provable re-encryption target

Tags: proxy-re-encryption

Suppose Alice has encrypted some plaintext $P$ to Bob. Bob wishes to re-encrypt this information to Charlie via proxy, in such a manner that:

1. The proxy cannot obtain $P$
2. The proxy can prove that Bob has provided a valid re-encryption key, meaning that Charlie will be able to obtain $P$ by decrypting with his private key
3. The proxy can prove that the ciphertext originated from Alice

Is such a scheme possible?

Comment: Q3 implies that there is some kind of sender authentication, which is not typical in public-key encryption

Comment: For Q2: Proxy can forward the ciphertext directly to Charlie. Why is this not suitable?

Answer (score 2):

PRE schemes guarantee Q1, if they are even remotely worthwhile.
Alice could add a signature over her public signing key and the ciphertext to accomplish Q3.
I haven't seen any works that guarantee a re-encryption key from B to C is valid.